# What is ODBC doing behind the scenes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sockets, tcp, odbc

I would like to know if ODBC is sending the SQL Commands over TCP/IP  Protocol to the SQL Server?

I couldn't find a simple answer to the question.

Reference I read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx

Comment: Depends on the configuration, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's the ODBC Driver Manager which upon receiving the request polls the ODBC drivers existing and delegates the query request to that specific driver. It's then the job of that driver to carry out the operation and yes it does send the query over network (or over tcp socket).

If you are on a linux server then if you go to `/tmp` directory; you will find the unnamed pipe or temporary socket created.